# Mysql converting varchar column values to datetime

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have table column with datatype as VARCHAR(255) and value in it as "Dec 31 1969 18:00:00".
I need to convert this value in date format like Y-m-d H:i:s i.e. 1969-12-31 18:00:00
Tried with the solution using [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), but is not working anymore. I tried like -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Dec 31 1969 18:00:00','%M %d,%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

BUt, this returns NULL.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the comma (`,`) from the format.
- `%M` is the full name of the month, not abbreviated, like `%b`.
- `%h` is 12-hour hours value. Use `%H` or use `%T` for the whole time part.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Dec 31 1969 18:00:00','%b %d %Y %T')
```